# Approach ASP.Net core dependency injection when using scoped configuration object registration per request

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm building an WebAPI method that needs to support specific scoped configuration registrations per the content of the request.

I have an existing service library that expects a configuration object to be injected at construction of a lower level service. The API controller's constructor is injected with a higher level service which has a dependency on the lower level.  DI is handling the dependency tree nicely.

My first thought is to change the configuration object to a Scoped lifetime and create a middleware component to intercept the request and change the configuration object properties based on the request.

What is the proper approach to this given the new Microsoft approach to dependency injection in ASP.Net Core?

Answer (score 0):

I found that by using a middleware component I could register the configuration as Scoped:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyConfiguration, MyConfiguration>();
```

And then change it in the middleware:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var config = context.RequestServices.GetService<IMyConfiguration>();
    config.Value = "foobar";
    _logger.LogInformation($"MyMiddleware: {config.Id}");
    await _next(context);
}
```

I just need to examine the context to pull my configuration.